# Android file.exists returns false for reasons unknown

Tags: android, file

here is the code:

```
        public void fromJs() throws Exception {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String data = null;
    File file;

    Toast.makeText(this, "" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    file = new File(Main3Activity.this.getFilesDir(), mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + ".json");

    Toast.makeText(this, "" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (file.exists()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "FILE exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

        data = convertStreamToString(fin);

        ArrayList<Item> v = new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>() {
        }.getType());




        fin.close();



        new BackGroundWorkerInserItems().execute(v);

    }else {


        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "NO FILE EXISTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

When I click the button at first it says the File does not exist but if I click it again it then works I have been stuck here for 3 hours trying to figure out what is wrong but the code seems fine it was working fine earlier, I traced the error back to this function I don't know what I should do, its driving me mad.

Do note that the file does exists it being downloaded from a server and then after that I fire up this function.

Comment: I see no button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the user authentication, it might return false because the user authentication didn't work. Create another user to see if it works or not.

Comment: User is not false since the toast is returning the user id